# Fetch all Facebook Groups user created or admin of

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having an issue fetching all groups an authenticated user created or is an admin of.

Here is the endpoint I used:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/${userId}/groups?access_token=${accessToken}&admin_only=true&fields=administrator,id,name,icon,cover,permissions,privacy
```

The above endpoint is not returning groups the user created. It is only returning other groups the user is an admin of. This is very weird. I feel that if I created a group I should automatically be an admin to that group. Is that not how it supposed to be? Or is there another endpoint that can help me achieve what I want?

I want to fetch all Facebook groups the user created or is an admin of.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the `admin_only` filter doesn't work properly. With `admin_only=true`, I get no groups at all (although I am admin in several), and with `admin_only=false` I get all my groups (groups I am in, or am an admin of) - when I request the `administrator` field, there's groups with `true` and groups with `false` in the result.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for responding. Now surprisingly, the administrator field is returning ```administrator:false``` for groups that the user created. This is really weird.

Comment: I am getting true for all my groups I created myself, and for the others I was made an admin of. And I don't think you can differentiate between the two cases.

Comment: I am getting ```"administrator": false``` for all groups I created myself. I'm very much confused right now. This is really weird

Comment: @CBroe Please if there is another way to get this right that you can recommend. I would truly appreciate. I'm under pressure to get this right. Groups created by the authenticated user is returning ```"administrator": false```. I have no idea why?

Comment: Is the user actually still an admin of the group? Or has perhaps someone else taken over that role, and the original creator was removed from the admins at some point?

Comment: @CBroe He confirmed that he's still an admin to the group. He also was the original person that created the group. So, it's really weird that the response is coming back as ```"administrator": false``` for him. Also I noticed that Facebook has deprecated the ```owner``` field. If not maybe that may have helped as well

Comment: @CBroe please I am still having this issue again. Any recommendations?